# Show window titles in window switcher in Ubuntu

Tags: gnome, window-manager

I'm relatively new to Ubuntu/Gnome.

When I used KDE in BSD, I liked how <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd> shows all window titles in a vertical list. I often have 20 windows open, so this is really helpful. I even tried Kubuntu last night but I think this new KDE is way too complicated. Also, I got overwhelmed by all the options so I went back to Ubuntu.

Mine is purely a workstation and I don’t want any fancy effects, thumbnails of the screenshot, or anything. I’m just looking for a plain <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd> box with icon-title on each line.

I did a ton of extensive searches online, and saw screenshots of *compiz*, but it seems to just be super fancy visual effects, and still doesn’t give me the vertical list I want.

Does anyone know what I can use for this?

Answer (score 0):

Openbox provides a vertical task list (client-list-combined-menu) that you can bind to any key(s) or mouse button you want. The only difference is that in Openbox you *click* on the window you want to bring forward (or press the first letter).